# Query with OR conditions, mongodb/mognoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is (a part) of my model:

```
var materialSchema = new Schema({
  ownerType:  { type: String, required: true},
  organization: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'organization'
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
  },
});
```

I want to make a query that returns:

- ownerType = 'public'
- organization = 321

The condition are 'OR'. So the material should be either ownerType 'public' or organization 321.

Can not find this in the docs. Do I need to make nested queries with "find" to do this? Or can it be done with a single query?

Some pseudo code:

```
    mongoose.model('material').find({ownerType:'public' || organization:321}, function(err,materials){
...
}
```

Comment: There is no property "orgainization: 321" with matching data. Perhaps you mean in the "referenced" object, which implies a join. MongoDB does not do joins. Model differently.

Comment: 321 was just example. In the actual query it's an objectId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well presuming that your actual "Model" is named `Material` then you would come out to something like this in MongoDB parlance:

```
Material.find(
    {
        "$or": [
            { "ownerType": "public" },
            { "orginization._id": 123 }
        ]
    },
    function(err,docs) {
       // results in here
    }
);
```

So MongoDB has an [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator, which makes sense since the query operands are represented in BSON ( from JSON conversion in the JavaScript case ). The purpose presents an "array" of possible arguments which are evaluated in a "short circuit" manner to determine if either case results in a `true` condition to match your query criteria.